# Arc voltage on the relay's contacts when load is off

Tags: relay, arc, contact

The contacts of the relay (not the coil of the relay) are connected in series with water boiler (2kW) and AC power socket (220V, 50Hz). Suddenly, relay stops its operation due to the electric arc which continuously appeared at commutation of high power electrical device.

The question is following. What is approximate voltage (EMF), which appears on the commutation contacts of the relay?

Additionally, the datasheet for the relay may be found [here](http://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/power/JQX-14F-1C.pdf).

P.S. My colleague tells me that wire has no inductance, but I am not agree. The wire is of 5m length, so the approximate inductance is equal to L=8444nH, then U=L*dI/dt. dI and dt are unknown and I cannot even imagine approximate values.

P.S. If someone took the measurement for such kind of situation using oscilloscope, please share your results!

Comment: approximately 220V

Comment: If you're concerned about the wire inductance, then you have to know the maximum current in the system. Assuming a 2kW resistive load, you can figure the *peak* current from 220VAC (RMS). Relay opening will be on the millisecond timescale. However, your inductance calculation (too many sig. fig.!) seems not to take into account the fact that AC power lines are usually very close to each other and carrying total zero current.

Comment: I'm not sure about "Relay opening will be on the millisecond timescale". I think it is shorter. If to calculate EMF considering your assumption, it is equal to 8444e-9H*(2000W/220V)/1e-6s = 76.8 V. Don't you think it is very small?

Comment: An approximate inductance for 5m of wire would be 8uH, not something with 10 significant figures!

Comment: The question is not in the representation of the number ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about inductive EMF we can calculate that. Let's assume that we go from 10 A to zero in 1 ms. This seems a reasonable minimum time value as the contactor is mechanical and the mains is only at peak value for a fraction of each half-cycle anyway. Let's also assume that your value of 8 uH is correct. (I'm not going to check.)

$$ V = L \frac {di}{dt} = 8\times 10^{-6} \frac{10}{10^{-3}} = 8 \times 10 ^{-2} = 80~mV $$

I don't think you need worry about that.

[image]

*Figure 1. (left) Pristine contacts from a relay
(right) The nearly destroyed contacts from a relay operated under power for nearly 100,000 cycles. Source: Wikipedia [Arc Suppression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_suppression).*

The contact wear will come from the arcing and decreased contact area and pressure as the contacts open and close. Additional heat will be generated at this time.

Update (after OP supplied datasheet):

[image]

*Figure 2. Extract from [datasheet](http://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/power/JQX-14F-1C.pdf).*

That relay is too small despite the manufacturer's specification. How do I know? It failed!

Note that with 100 mΩ contact resistance (and not 100 MΩ as stated) that at 10 A you will have \$ P = I^2R = 10^2 \times 0.1 = 10~W \$ dissipated by the contacts.
That contact resistance is quoted at 6 V so that's probably worst case but it gives some idea of the hardship the device endures

Secondly, since it's a DC coil I presume you are switching it electronically and have a snubber diode across the coil. This will slow down the release and increase the problem dramatically.

Tell your colleague that inductance is not the problem here.

---

OP's comment:

> Anyway, I cannot agree with thansistor's [sic] prove, because calculations hasn't took into account the real value of inductance, which is unknown for the complete electrical circuit...

OK. What is the supply impedance? A quick web search brought me to an audio enthusiast site, [Acoustica](http://www.acoustica.org.uk/other/mains_Z.html). (These guys worry about everything.)

> One of the factors frequently overlooked by the hifi comics is that the electrical mains is not infinitely powerful; more specifically it can exhibit significant reluctance to supply enough electrons. Sometimes the impression is left that you could have the entire output of SIzewell B [a British nuclear power station] on tap if you buy a big enough power cord. In this year's colour, of course....
>
> It ain't necessarily so; it ain't even close. IEC725:1981 models the European domestic mains supply as having an impedance of (0.4+j0.25)ohms. Surprisingly, measurement shows that the UK agrees with or somewhat betters the model on the whole, at something like (0.25+j0.23) ohms. What does that really mean? It's a definition which include the real resistance of the distribution network and wiring up to the socket, estimated as 0.25ohms, plus the reactive (j) component, allowing for stray capacitance and inductance of the wiring. The impedance is dominated by inductance, and equates to roughly 0.23ohms in the UK, for a net supply impedance of nearly 0.5ohms at 50Hz.

I haven't verified these numbers but let's take the inductance of the mains at your water heater supply as having a 0.25 Ω inductive impedance. We can calculate the inductance as follows:

$$ L = \frac {X_L}{2 \pi f} = \frac {0.25}{2 \pi 50} = 8 \times 10^{-4}~H $$

Plugging these back into our first equation and ignoring the \$ 8 \times 10^{-6} ~H \$ of the heater wiring we get:

$$ V = L \frac {di}{dt} = 8 \times 10^{-4} \frac{10}{10^{-3}} = 8~V $$

I think you can tell your colleague that we're still OK. Inductance isn't the problem.

I've never looked at this problem before so please let me know if I have missed something.

**Links**

There is another reference to IEC 725:1981 in [The Influence of Source Impedance in Electrical Characterization of Solid State LOighting Sources](http://www.euramet.org/Media/docs/Repository/A169/ENG05_Lighting/VSL_EL_1.pdf) by D. Zhao and G. Rietveld, VSL, Dutch Metrology Institute below equation (6) on page 3. This uses the same 0.4+0.25j Ω as the Acoustica source.

Comment: I found, that dielectric strength for air is 20...75 (kV/inch). Then, in turn, if to suppose that arc length is of 1(mm), then voltage for this arc is 0.78...2.95(kV). What do you think about such assumption?

Comment: @VictorSignaevskyi You have it the wrong way around. You've selected an arbitary (unknown) distance (1mm) and then worked out what the voltage to breakdown air would be. You need to start with the (known) voltage you have and then work out the distance it could strike the arc. Its clear from transistor's calculation that **the back emf (80mV) is not the issue** so the only voltage involved in any arcing is the supply. Assuming the break comes at the very peak of the cycle that gives 308V max (220*1.4). Taking your worst case value (20kV/inch) gives an arc length of 0.015 inchs / 0.4mm

Comment: ... at which point the arc will extinguish.

Comment: @JImDearden Your explanation looks correct, but it doesn't take into account inductance (taking into account EMF we should get voltage larger than 220*sqrt(2)). Moreover, I think, inductance is of much higher level than I thought before. My colleague told me, that we should take into account not only the length of wire walking through the socket, relay and water boiler... Also we must include all wire through which current flows. I mean we should take into account whole wire (for example, from transformer to the customer). I think I should measure inductance in the socket...

Comment: What are you trying to solve here? Are you trying to figure out why a real relay stopped working? What stopped - the armature stopped moving or the contacts stopped conducting? Link to datasheet for relay?

Comment: @transistor Yes, I am trying to figure out the reason why relay stopped working. The basic problem is in stuck of the relay contacts and I'm just wondering what is the reason. The relay datasheet may be found [here](http://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/power/JQX-14F-1C.pdf).

Comment: Why did you not include the datasheet in your original question? It is essential information. See update.

Comment: @VictorSignaevskyi I too think this relay is under-rated for this job. You seem to be fixated on back emf **which transistor has clearly shown is not the problem.** The reason the contacts fail is due to the high current they have to pass (9A) which causes spot welds or 'pitting' (resistance heating) on the contact's surface. increasing the contact resistance each time. (see transistor's picture of contacts). Eventually the damage builds up through a number of repetitions and eventually the contacts fuse together. This is a perfectly normal failure mode and is cured by replacing the relay.

Comment: ... with a better one.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot agree with thansistor's prove, because calculations hasn't took into account the real value of inductance, which is unknown for the complete electrical circuit... I can agree only with advice to use more powerful relay such as current was underrated. But the question of the topic is not in the problem of the relay selection.

Comment: Well then please un-accept the answer for a while and see if a better one comes along. Others are less likely to give an answer if you have accepted one.

Comment: See the update. Satisfied yet? I seem to be doing all the work here.

Comment: @transistor Thank you for such nice clarification about "inductance in the socket"! I can agree with it and yes, I am satisfied about the inductance. But we have another item in the denominator U=L*dI/dt. Do you agree that the disconnection of the relay contacts requires considerably less time than 1 millisecond? As I understand, electrical connection became lost even after 1uS after start disconnection.

P.S. As we can see, emf value has changed considerably from 80mV to 8V, so where is a guarantee, that it may not change its value even more due to time dt, which is in denominator...

Comment: It will change with _dt_ but see my point about slow drop-out of the DC relay. I think you have enough information to do your own calculations now! ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Relay sounds sticky, unless your load is inductive as well as resistive (wire wound). Also, check the driver circuit for proper operation w/respect to voltage & current to the coil. Other possibility is the coil on relay could have a shorted winding.